# What do i need to do to upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10 (and eventually to 16.04)

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

I'm stuck on Ubuntu 15.04, i followed some outdated guide on Reddit to update from 15.04 to 15.10 and screwed up my  /etc/apt/sources.list, i get a bunch of the following when trying to update:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

So how do i update from 15.04 to 15.10 and eventually to 16.04?

My dedicated server provider only offers 14.04, 14.10 and 15.04 on prebuilt servers so i cant freshly install it.

Comment: *My dedicated server provider only offers 14.04, 14.10 and 15.04* If so start with 14.04 which is still supported and, if possible, upgrade to 16.04 from there.

Comment: Although you can upgrade through multiple versions, it is going to be faster and more reliable to do a fresh install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wily Ubuntu and their corresponding repository reached the end of life. The official repository have been migrated to a dedicated end of life location.

To upgrade your ubuntu, you must update the location of the repositories in your sources list file (`/etc/apt/sources.list`) by using the following instead.

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Note that you must update the `apt` local database before trying to install or upgrade the packages.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Once upgraded, you should be able to easily upgrade to 16.10 as this version is still supported.